# Window.print() is not working in ie, but working in all other browsers

Tags: javascript

I know the question I am asking has been already discussed here. But I couldnt find any definite solution.
I am working on a project in `Drupal 7`, where I want to take print out. I have charts and some other contents to be printed. I used `window.open()` to created new window and append all the styles and js (`chart.js`, `jquery.js` etc) to newly created window to get the style. And window.print() to print. My code is working in `firefox` and `chrome`, but not in `IE`. I am attaching the code I used below.

```
var mywindow = window.open('', 'print', 'scrollbars=1,height=600,width=600');
mywindow.document.write("<html><head><title>Patient Data</title><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='" + Drupal.settings.basePath + "sites/all/themes/prescribewell/css/style.css'>");
mywindow.document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='" + Drupal.settings.basePath + "sites/all/themes/prescribewell/css/bootstrap.css'>");
mywindow.document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='" + Drupal.settings.basePath + "sites/all/themes/prescribewell/css/bootstrap.min.css'>");
mywindow.document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='" + Drupal.settings.basePath + "sites/all/themes/prescribewell/css/bootstrap-theme.css'>");
mywindow.document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='" + Drupal.settings.basePath + "sites/all/themes/prescribewell/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'>");
mywindow.document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='" + Drupal.settings.basePath + "sites/all/themes/prescribewell/css/font-awesome.css'>");
mywindow.document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='" + Drupal.settings.basePath + "sites/all/themes/prescribewell/css/font-style.css'>");
mywindow.document.write("<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></sc" + "ript>");
mywindow.document.write("<script src='" + Drupal.settings.basePath + "sites/all/themes/prescribewell/js/bootstrap.js'></sc" + "ript>");
mywindow.document.write("<script src='" + Drupal.settings.basePath + "sites/all/themes/prescribewell/js/bootstrap.min.js'></sc" + "ript>");
mywindow.document.write("<script src='" + Drupal.settings.basePath + "sites/all/themes/prescribewell/js/button.js'></sc" + "ript>");
mywindow.document.write("<script src='" + Drupal.settings.basePath + "sites/all/themes/prescribewell/js/prescribewell_leads_js.js'></sc" + "ript>");
mywindow.document.write("<script src='" + Drupal.settings.basePath + "sites/all/modules/Prescribewell_leeds/prescription.js'></sc" + "ript>");

mywindow.document.write("</head><body>");
mywindow.document.write(datas.resPres); //content to be printed as json response...

mywindow.document.write("</body>");
if (summary == 1) {
    mywindow.document.write("<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></sc" + "ript>");
    mywindow.document.write("<script src='" + Drupal.settings.basePath + "sites/all/modules/prescribewell_charts/Chart.js'></sc" + "ript>");
    mywindow.document.write("<script src='" + Drupal.settings.basePath + "sites/all/modules/prescribewell_charts/clinicchart.js'></sc" + "ript>");
    mywindow.document.write("<script src='" + Drupal.settings.basePath + "sites/all/modules/Prescribewell_leeds/print.js'></sc" + "ript>");
}
mywindow.document.write("</html>");

if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
    window.print();
} else {

    setTimeout(function () {

        mywindow.document.close();
        mywindow.focus();
        mywindow.print();
        //mywindow.close();

    }, 5000);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: provide us fiddle please

Comment: You will have to tell us what your debugging has revealed, more than just "it is not working". What _does_ happen? What errors? What experiments have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You code have a condition for IE:

```
if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
    window.print();
} else {
    //other code
}
```

**Other code** block is a cross-browser and must work in IE:

```
mywindow.document.close();//close document after write
mywindow.focus();//set focus back
mywindow.print();//start print dialog
//mywindow.close();
```

So just remove `if/else` with `IE` check.